# angular change filtered ng-repeat scenarios with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I have four filtered scenarios I want the user to be able to click through. I have a different ng-repeat filter for each scenario.

```
<div ng-model="topic0" ng-repeat="post in postCtrl.getAllPosts() | orderBy :'-votes' ">
        <div ng-model="topic1" ng-repeat=" post in postCtrl.getAllPosts() | filter:{topicId:'1'} | orderBy :'-votes'"> ">
            <div ng-model="topic2" ng-repeat=" post in postCtrl.getAllPosts() | filter:{topicId:'2'} | orderBy :'-votes'"> ">
                <div ng-model="topic3" ng-repeat=" post in postCtrl.getAllPosts() | filter:{topicId:'3'} | orderBy :'-votes'">
```

And these are my buttons:

```
<a class="btn-flat topic" >All</a>
<a class="btn-flat topic">Inspire</a>
<a class="btn-flat topic">Show Off</a>
<a class="btn-flat topic">Share</a>
```

How do I set it up so that each filtered ng-repeat scenario is only triggered when a tab is clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you filter by a variable instead, that way you can change the variable value using ng-click and the list will be updated?

Comment: Just tried that and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="btn-flat topic" ng-click="postCtrl.topicId = undefined">All</a>
    <a class="btn-flat topic" ng-click="postCtrl.topicId = 1">Inspire</a>
    <a class="btn-flat topic" ng-click="postCtrl.topicId = 2">Show Off</a>
    <a class="btn-flat topic" ng-click="postCtrl.topicId = 3">Share</a>

<div ng-model="topic0" ng-repeat="post in postCtrl.getAllPosts() | orderBy :'-votes' | filter: { topicId: postCtrl.topicId}">
```